# why isn't celery task asyncing while loading page?

Tags: django, heroku, celery

the task runs but my page waits for it to finish the task then loads the page. Pretty much defeats the purpose of async plus I am getting a timedout on heroku--separate issue. So, I am calling the task in `views.py` and sending it to `tasks.py`. Not sure what else I need, but logically looks right to me?

settings.py

```
BROKER_URL=['amqp://guest@localhost//','cloudamqp']
BROKER_POOL_LIMIT = 1
BROKER_CONNECTION_MAX_RETRIES = None
CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULER = 'djcelery.schedulers.DatabaseScheduler'
CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = 'pickle',
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json', 
CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND='djcelery.backends.database:DatabaseBackend'
CELERY_ALWAYS_EAGER = True
```

views.py

```
def my_page(request):
    #do something 

    #this is at the end, right before return. 
    #If I put it in the middle, it runs in sequence. So I don't see anything after this until the task is done.
    get_data.delay(args) 
    return (request, 'home.html')
```

tasks.py

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
import requests
import json
import time
import sys
import os
import random
from os import path
from celery import Celery
sys.path.append( path.dirname( path.dirname( path.abspath(__file__) ) ) )
from lib import myfiles
from django.db import models
from .models import mymodels
import django
django.setup()

@task(name="get_myfunction")
def get_data(user, items):
    #runs a bunch of things
    #saves data
    #all this and page spinner on the browser tab just keeps spinning until its done
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`CELERY_ALWAYS_EAGER = True` should be `CELERY_ALWAYS_EAGER = False`

From [the docs](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/configuration.html#task-always-eager):

> If this is True, all tasks will be executed locally by blocking until
>   the task returns.